# React Router DefaultRoute Not Rendering

Tags: react-router, url-routing, reactjs

I'm attempting to configure React-Router to work with my app (it doesn't do a ton yet).  I've attempted to use this configuration, but the DefaultRoute does not ever render, just the base route.

```jsx
var routes = (
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={LoginForm} />
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.body);
})
```

There is no error, LoginForm just never gets rendered (although App does). LoginForm and App both exist (so they should be able to be rendered). Am I just misunderstanding the way React-Router/DefaultRoute is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/), the second parameter to `Router.run` should be a `Location` object (either `Hash` or `History`).

```
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;

// declare our routes and their hierarchy
var routes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home}/>
    <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
    <Route path="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
  </Route>
);

var App = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
});
```